# How do you update a Dataset made up of joined tables

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview

I have 3 tables simplified to the below:

**main_table**

id | attribute1_id | attribute2_id | price

**attribute1_table**

id | attribute_name

**attribute2_table**

id | attribute_name

I've created a view in Sql Server that joins the tables together to give me the following output:

**main_table**

id | attribute1_id | attribute2_id | attribute1_name | attribute2_name | price

The problem I have is I want to be able to show the data in a DataGridView and allow the price to be editable. But I've created a "view" which I take it this is not the correct thing to use (i.e it's called a "view" which doesn't sound editable?)

I know I could create my own script to go through and update only the "main_table" but I think there must be a way to use DataGridView / Linked datasets with joined tables?

-

Answer (score 0):

Best thing I can advise is to create a stored procedure that takes all of the parameters and then within that procedure do the individual update statements to the table. Should work fairly well.